# Why does is.na() change its argument?

Tags: r

I just discovered the following behaviour of the `is.na()` function which I don't understand:

```
df <- data.frame(a = 5:1, b = "text")
df
##   a    b
## 1 5 text
## 2 4 text
## 3 3 text
## 4 2 text
## 5 1 text
is.na(df)
##          a     b
## [1,] FALSE FALSE
## [2,] FALSE FALSE
## [3,] FALSE FALSE
## [4,] FALSE FALSE
## [5,] FALSE FALSE
is.na(df) <- "0"
df
##   a    b  0
## 1 5 text NA
## 2 4 text NA
## 3 3 text NA
## 4 2 text NA
## 5 1 text NA
```

**My question**
Why does `is.na()` change its argument (and in this case adds an extra column to the data frame)? In this case its behaviour seems extra puzzling (or at least unexpected) because the result of the query is `FALSE` for all instances.

**NB**
This question is not about subsetting and changing the `NA` values in a data frame - I know how to do that (`df[is.na(df)] <- "0"`). This question is about the behaviour of the `is.na` function! Why is an assignment to a `is.something` function changing the argument itself - this is unexpected.

Comment: You need to use those logical variables as index reference, i.e.  `df[is.na(df)] <- 0`

Comment: @Sotos: Please see my comment.

Comment: @vonjd I saw your comment, but my point is that your assignment is not working even if there are NA values i.e. `df$a[3] <- NA;
 is.na(df) <- "0"`

Comment: @akrun: I know but why is an `is.something` changing the argument itself - this is unexpected, is it not?

Comment: @vonjd I don't remember I ever used this kind of assignment.  But you can use something like `is.na(df) <- df==4`

Comment: ```is.na<-``` and `is.na` aren't the same function.

Comment: @vonjd it's [documented](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/NA.html)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The actual function being used here is not `is.na()` but the assignment function `` `is.na<-` ``, for which the default method is `` `is.na<-.default` ``. Printing that function to console we see:

```
function (x, value) 
{
    x[value] <- NA
    x
}
```

So clearly, `value` is supposed to be an index here. If you index a `data.frame` like `df["0"]`, it will try to select the column named `"0"`. If you *assign* something to `df["0"]`, the column will be created and filled with (in this case) `NA`.

To clarify, `` `is.na<-` `` sets values to `NA`, it does *not* replace `NA` values with something else.

Comment: Thank you, so the point I missed was that in this case an assignment to `is.na` actually *sets* values to `NA`. I would have *never* thought this possible.

Comment: It is documented but perhaps a little surprising, yes.

Comment: It's exactly the same way that rownames() and colnames() works, just as other examples.  These do both get and set.  It's actually very consistent syntax.