# r, assign an NA value to each row in my b column corresponding to NA in my a column

Tags: r, dataframe, na

i'm trying to assign an NA value to each row in my b column corresponding to NA in my a column. 
The columns are in a data frame df.

But when i do the following code, all my b column gets NA.

What should i change ?

```
  for(i in 1:nrow(df)) 
{
  row <- df[i,]
  is.na(df$`a`) <- (df$b  <- NA)
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does is.na() change its argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42107628/why-does-is-na-change-its-argument)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this, we can make use ofthe vectorized option by creating a logical `vector` (`is.na(df$a)`), use this to subset the elements of 'b' and assign it to `NA`

```
 df$b[is.na(df$a)] <- NA
```

---

If we are using `data.table`, this can be assigned (`:=`) in place

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[is.na(a), b := NA]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation `?is.na`, `is.na<-` is a *generic function which sets elements to `NA`*. For the right hand side of `is.na(x) <- value`, `value` needs to be *a suitable index vector for use with x*.

Examples:

```
df <- data.frame(a = LETTERS[1:5], b = 1:5)
is.na(df$b) <- c(2, 4)
df
#  a  b
#1 A  1
#2 B NA
#3 C  3
#4 D NA
#5 E  5
```

So, the 2nd and 4th elements of vector `df$b` have been set to `NA`.

Now, if the corresponding elements of `df$a` should be set to `NA`as well, we can use:

```
is.na(df$a) <- is.na(df$b)
df
#     a  b
#1    A  1
#2 <NA> NA
#3    C  3
#4 <NA> NA
#5    E  5
```

NB: I've learned about this feature from answers and comments on [Why does is.na() change its argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42107628/3817004)